# does 'cat' have to be included in the expression if we were to write array element (language C)

Tags: c

I have to write the array element of this function:

```
cat[a][b][c][d]
```

I'm pretty new to C so any help would be appreciated. I do know that the answer is either

```
*(*(*(*(a)+b)+c)+d)
```

or

```
*(*(*(*(cat+a)+b)+c)+d).
```

Comment: cat[a][b][c][d] is not a function.

Comment: What's wrong with using `cat[a][b][c][d] = some_value`?

Comment: i know, just wanted to know if cat is included while writing array elements

Comment: @NathanOliver nothing is wrong. I just have to write the array element of this function. Since it has cat before the arrays, i wanted to know if we included 'cat' while writing the array elements.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  What would `*(*(*(*(a)+b)+c)+d)` give you?  a, b, c, and d are integer after all.

Comment: If you just have the indexes (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) without the `cat` name, how would the compiler know what array (if any) you are referring to? What if you have a `cat` array and a `dog` array with the same dimensions?

Comment: @NathanOliver got it, thanks!

Comment: @AdrianMole yep understand the idea now thanks

Answer (score 2):

This expression

```
*(*(*(*(a)+b)+c)+d)
```

is syntactically incorrect provided that a, b, c, and d are integers.

To write an expression that yields the lvalue of an element of the array with indices a, b, c, d you can the following ways

```
cat[a][b][c][d]
```

or

```
 d[c[b[a[cat]]]]
```

or

```
*( *( *( *( cat + a ) + b ) + c ) + d )
```

or using a mixture of the subscript operator and the dereference operator as for example

```
*( ( *( cat[a] + b ) )[c] + d )
```

but in any case in all the expressions the name of the array must be present.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 4 };
    
    int cat[N][N][N][N] = { 0 };
    
    size_t a = 0, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3;
    
    cat[a][b][c][d] = 10;
    
    printf( "%d\n", *( *( *( *( cat + a ) + b ) + c ) + d ) );
    
    printf( "%d\n", d[c[b[a[cat]]]] );
    
    printf( "%d\n", *( ( *( cat[a] + b ) )[c] + d ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10
10
10
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard (6.5.2.1 Array subscripting)

> 2 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets []
> is a subscripted designation of an element of an array object. The
> definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to
> (*((E1)+(E2))). Because of the conversion rules that apply to the
> binary + operator, if E1 is an array object (equivalently, a pointer
> to the initial element of an array object) and E2 is an integer,
> E1[E2] designates the E2-th element of E1 (counting from zero).

And array designators used in the subscript operator are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

Comment: IMHO `d[c[b[a[cat]]]]` does not strictly follows the C Standard, as the interpretation of `a[cat]` would be the `cat`-th element of `a`, which is not the intention of the statement. It should therefore be avoided.

Comment: @gkhaos Reread the quote from the C Standard I provided. This expression (*((E1)+(E2))) may be equivalently rewritten ;like ( *(  ( E2 ) + ( E1 ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

If you had declared `int dog[9];`:

- `dog[a]` can be written `*(dog + a)`.
- The variable `dog` refers to a location in memory containing the first array element.
- Those elements are spaced `sizeof(int)` apart from each other.
- Expression `dog[a]` is the `a`th such element.

If you had declared `int cat[9][8][7][6];`:

- `cat[a][b][c][d]` can be written `*(*(*(*(cat + a) + b) + c) + d)`
- The variable `cat` refers to a location in memory containing the first array element.
- Those elements are spaced `sizeof(int)` apart from each other.
- Expression `cat[a][b][c][d]` is the `a*8*7*6 + b*7*6 + c*6 + d`th such element.